# I have in issue with filter function in my react ecommerce app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, e-commerce

**React filter function is working**

When I click on the filter option like "Denim", "shirt" etc it should filter the products and show only those items only. I used the `handleTag` function to filter the array of products and then update the `setfilterProducts` but it is not working.

Below my main file `Home.jsx`

```
function Home() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [filterProducts, setFileterProducts] = useState([]);
    const [sortValue, setSortValue] = useState('');
    const [tag, setTag] = useState('');
    // const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const loadAllProducts = () => {

    /*var myArray = ['a', 1, 'a', 2, '1'];

    let unique = [...new Set(myArray)];

    console.log(unique); // unique is ['a', 1, 2, '1']*/
    let ar = data.map(item => item.tag);
    let uniqueEle = [...new Set(ar)];
    // console.log(uniqueEle);
    setProducts(data);
    setFileterProducts(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadAllProducts();
    handleSort();
    handleTag();
}, [filterProducts, sortValue, tag])

const handleSort = (value) => {
    setSortValue(value);
    listProducts();
}

function listProducts() {
    
    if(sortValue !== '') {
        // console.log("SORT: "+sortValue)
        products.sort((a, b) => sortValue === 'lowest' ? (parseInt(a.price) > parseInt(b.price) ? 1:-1) : (parseInt(a.price) < parseInt(b.price) ? 1:-1))
    } else {
        // console.log("INSIDE THE ELSE PART");
        products.sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1))
    }
    return {setFileterProducts: products}
}

const handleTag = (value) => {
    // console.log(value);
    setTag(value);
    listTagProduct();
}

function listTagProduct() {
    if(tag !== '') {
        if(tag === 'Denim') {
            console.log(tag);
            let filterAr = tagFilter(tag);
            console.log("FilterArr "+filterAr);
            return {setFileterProducts: filterAr}
        } else if(tag === "T-shirt") {
            let filterAr = tagFilter(tag);
            return {setFileterProducts: filterAr}
        } else if(tag === "shirt") {
            let filterAr = tagFilter(tag);
            return {setFileterProducts: filterAr}
        } else if(tag === "jacket") {
            let filterAr = tagFilter(tag);
            return {setFileterProducts: filterAr}
        }
    }
    return {setFileterProducts: products}
}

// utility function
function tagFilter(tag) {
    let ar = filterProducts.filter(item => item.tag === "Denim");
    // console.log(ar);
    return ar;
}

return (
    <div className =  "container-fluid">
        <h2>All Products: {filterProducts.length}</h2>
        <Filter 
            product = {filterProducts} 
            handleSort = {handleSort} 
            sort = {sortValue}
            handleTag = {handleTag}
            tag = {tag}
        />
        <hr />
        <div className="row custom-card">
                {filterProducts.map((product, idx) => {
                    console.log(product);
                    return(
                        
                   

     <div key = {product.id} className="col-md-3 mb-2">
                                <Card products = {product}/>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

    export default Home
```

This uses to display the filter options `Filter.jsx`

```
function Filter(props) {
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        // console.log(event.target.value);
        return props.handleSort(event.target.value);
    }

const handleTagChange = (event) => {
    // console.log(event.target.value);
    return props.handleTag(event.target.value);
}
let tagNames = ["T-shirt", "shirt", "Denim", "jacket"];
return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
                <p className = " mr-2">Filters:<span className="mr-4"></span>
                    {tagNames.map((item, idx) => (
                        <span key = {idx} >
                            <button 
                                type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 custom-filter"
                                value= {item}
                                onClick = {handleTagChange}
                            >{item}</button>
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </p>
                </div>
            <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
            <select className="form-control" value = {props.sort} onChange = {handleChange}>
                {/* {console.log("CHECKING: "+props.sort)} */}
                <option value="">Sort by</option>
                <option value="lowest">lowest to highest</option>
                <option value="highest">highest to lowest</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}

    export default Filter
```

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ecommerce-ku0sw?file=/src/components/core/card/Card.jsx)

[image: filter is not working(when I click on the filter option like Denim it should only the Denim product)]

Comment: can anybody please me with that

Answer (score 1):

Your `Filter.jsx` looks alright and should work fine. I only made a few simple changes like moving the `onClick` event handlers inline, and added the selected button some styles to distinguish its state.

#### Mutating the state directly

On the other hand, your `Home.jsx` looks overcomplicated, so I needed to clean things up. One of the biggest mistakes was mutating the states directly. It can lead to really odd bugs. You probably didn't even noticed that you changed the state, but `products.sort` for example mutates the original `products` array.

You should clone the array first (you can use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)), sort the clone, and update the state with this new sorted array.

#### Weird return statements

Another problem is returning objects like `{setFileterProducts: products}`, or `{setFileterProducts: filterAr}`. I'm not sure what you wanted to do, maybe it meant to be `setFileterProducts(filterAr)`?

#### The useEffect hooks

The next problem is the usage of the `useEffect` hook. You tried to `loadAllProducts` every time a filter tag, a sort by value, or the filtered products change which is absolutely unnecessary.

You could instead use two `useEffects`; one to load the data from the API and set the `products` and `filteredProducts` states, and another one to update `filteredProducts` every time the tag or sort value changes. You don't need anything else because whenever the `filteredProducts` array changes, React re-renders the component.

#### Some more simplification

I changed a few variable names and I tried to remove every unnecessary lines from `Home.jsx`; only the states, the two `useEffect` hooks, and the return statement stayed. Filter and sort is handled by the hook, there is no need to use additional functions for these.

I also simplified the sort functions. If you want to [sort numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#creating_displaying_and_sorting_an_array), you just need to subtract them (and as subtraction changes the price's type to a number, you don't even need to use `parseInt` anymore).

`Home.jsx`

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import data from "../../../data.json";
import Card from "../card/Card.jsx";
import Filter from "../filter/Filter.jsx";
import "./Home.css";

function Home() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("");
  const [selectedTag, setSelectedTag] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setProducts(data);
    setFilteredProducts(data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = selectedTag
      ? products.filter((item) => item.tag === selectedTag)
      : products;

    setFilteredProducts(
      sortBy
        ? [...filtered].sort((a, b) =>
            sortBy === "lowest" ? a.price - b.price : b.price - a.price
          )
        : [...filtered].sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1))
    );
  }, [selectedTag, sortBy, products]);

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <h2>Products: {filteredProducts.length}</h2>
      <Filter
        handleSort={setSortBy}
        handleTagChange={setSelectedTag}
        selectedTag={selectedTag}
        sortBy={sortBy}
      />
      <hr />
      <div className="row custom-card">
        {filteredProducts.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id} className="col-md-3 mb-2">
            <Card products={product} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

`Filter.jsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Filter.css";

function Filter({ handleSort, handleTagChange, selectedTag, sortBy }) {
  let tagNames = ["T-shirt", "shirt", "Denim", "jacket"];

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-9">
          <p className=" mr-2">
            Filters: <span className="mr-4"></span>
            {tagNames.map((tag, idx) => (
              <button
                key={idx}
                type="button"
                className={`btn mr-2 custom-filter ${
                  selectedTag === tag
                    ? "btn-secondary"
                    : "btn-outline-secondary"
                }`}
                onClick={(e) => handleTagChange(e.target.value)}
                value={tag}
              >
                {tag}
              </button>
            ))}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
          <select
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => handleSort(e.target.value)}
            value={sortBy}
          >
            <option value="">Sort by</option>
            <option value="lowest">Lowest to highest</option>
            <option value="highest">Highest to lowest</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Filter;
```

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ecommerce-forked-wp1x1)